# Не появляется иконка svg

Tags: html, html5, svg

Не отображается иконка в svg формате.
Прописал так:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 94.926 94.926" style="enable-background:new 0 0 94.926 94.926;" xml:space="preserve">
 <symbol>
  <path             d="M55.931,47.463L94.306,9.09c0.826-0.827,0.826-2.167,0-2.994L88.833,0.62C88.436,0.224,87.896,0,87.335,0
    c-0.562,0-1.101,0.224-1.498,0.62L47.463,38.994L9.089,0.62c-0.795-0.795-2.202-0.794-2.995,0L0.622,6.096
    c-0.827,0.827-0.827,2.167,0,2.994l38.374,38.373L0.622,85.836c-0.827,0.827-0.827,2.167,0,2.994l5.473,5.476
    c0.397,0.396,0.936,0.62,1.498,0.62s1.1-0.224,1.497-0.62l38.374-38.374l38.374,38.374c0.397,0.396,0.937,0.62,1.498,0.62 s1.101-0.224,1.498-0.62l5.473-5.476c0.826-0.827,0.826-2.167,0-2.994L55.931,47.463z"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>


<div class="modalRecall__close">
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="#Capa_1" class="capa_1"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Файл close.svg - это одна единственная иконка, не спрайт.
Всё уже перепробовал. ПО id помоему определение делаю - это уже лишнее?
Через стили появляется, бекграундом.

А мне нужно именно через разметку выводить её.
В мозилле стала отображаться, а в остальных браузерах нет(

В инспекторе смотрю DOM - различий нет абсолютно в разных браузерах, но иконки появляются лишь в firefox.

Chrome пишет:
Error:  attribute width: Expected length, "auto".
Хотя width="auto" и стоит.

Comment: Просто как статичную каритнку нужно вывести? Если до просто через img src

Comment: @Nice Добавьте код иконки в вопрос

Comment: @Nilsan  Добавьте код иконки в вопрос. Что-то я не пойму, вы сменили ник? Поэтому не видите ответ и комментарии?

Comment: Прошу прощения, я вижу вопрос. Ник не менял. Просто напросто я ушел отдыхать сразу как написал свое сообщение)

Comment: @Nice Понятно. Код иконки не забудьте добавить в вопрос, без него никак. Или разместите на `jsfiddle.net`, если код большой

Comment: @Nice Топик будет закрыт, как дубликат, если в течение суток вы не ответите. Так  как подобных вопросов много и для решения вашего вопроса нужна конкретная информация. Без неё вопрос не имеет смысла.

Comment: Александр, прошу прощения. Было очень некогда, я сейчас отредактирую вопрос, внесу туда код иконки и т.д.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Код добавления `svg` иконки в `HTML` у вас абсолютно верный для случая, когда изображение svg сохранено в отдельный файл и находится в папке или на сетевом ресурсе с указанием естественно полного URL

```html
<div>
  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/check.svg" class="icon-after"></object>
  <svg id="iconsvg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 511.626 511.627" xml:space="preserve">
    <use xlink:href="img/check.svg#iconsvg1"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Без кода иконки, а в ней часто бывают причины отказа,  догадаться трудно, почему её не видно.

**Поэтому только предположения:**

1. В браузере `Chrome`  при запуске кода на `localhost` иконки не будет видно при добавлении с помощью `<object>`, только в сетевом размещении иконки работают. Либо локально тестируйте в `Firefox` у него иконку будет видно.
2. Если со стилями непорядок,- иконка не будет видна.
3. С масштабированием, позиционированием, что-то не так. `viewBox="0 0 511.626 511.627"` Иконка может находиться за пределами области видимости.

**update 19.12.2018**

Попробуйте добавить иконку svg самым надёжным способом - **инлайн**, то есть непосредственно в Html разметку.

- Код иконки, исключая шапку, нужно обернуть тегами 
  `<symbol id="facebook">...</symbol>` которые скроют содержание иконки до её вызова командой `<use>` и полностью скопировать код иконки в HTML
- Теперь в любом месте HTML можно многократно вызвать иконку

  `<svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 511.626 511.627" >
      <use xlink:href="#facebook" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    </svg>`

**Update 21.12.2018**

Теперь с кодом стали понятны причины

У вас  код иконки обернут тегами `<symbol>`, которые скрывают содержание 
Вызов содержания должен идти не через `id` svg, а через `id` `<symbol id="Capa_1">`

(Присвойте `ID` `<symbol="Capa_1">`, а у SVG уберите)

```css
.container {
width:25%;
height:25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 94.926 94.926" style="enable-background:new 0 0 94.926 94.926;" xml:space="preserve">
 <symbol id="Capa_1">
  <path             d="M55.931,47.463L94.306,9.09c0.826-0.827,0.826-2.167,0-2.994L88.833,0.62C88.436,0.224,87.896,0,87.335,0
    c-0.562,0-1.101,0.224-1.498,0.62L47.463,38.994L9.089,0.62c-0.795-0.795-2.202-0.794-2.995,0L0.622,6.096
    c-0.827,0.827-0.827,2.167,0,2.994l38.374,38.373L0.622,85.836c-0.827,0.827-0.827,2.167,0,2.994l5.473,5.476
    c0.397,0.396,0.936,0.62,1.498,0.62s1.1-0.224,1.497-0.62l38.374-38.374l38.374,38.374c0.397,0.396,0.937,0.62,1.498,0.62 s1.101-0.224,1.498-0.62l5.473-5.476c0.826-0.827,0.826-2.167,0-2.994L55.931,47.463z"/>
  </symbol>   
  
   <use xlink:href="#Capa_1" />
  
</svg> 

</div>
```

**Добавление  SVG (инлайн способ) непосредственно в HTML без тегов `<symbol>`**

```css
.container {
width:25%;
height:25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 94.926 94.926" style="enable-background:new 0 0 94.926 94.926;" xml:space="preserve">
 
  <path             d="M55.931,47.463L94.306,9.09c0.826-0.827,0.826-2.167,0-2.994L88.833,0.62C88.436,0.224,87.896,0,87.335,0
    c-0.562,0-1.101,0.224-1.498,0.62L47.463,38.994L9.089,0.62c-0.795-0.795-2.202-0.794-2.995,0L0.622,6.096
    c-0.827,0.827-0.827,2.167,0,2.994l38.374,38.373L0.622,85.836c-0.827,0.827-0.827,2.167,0,2.994l5.473,5.476
    c0.397,0.396,0.936,0.62,1.498,0.62s1.1-0.224,1.497-0.62l38.374-38.374l38.374,38.374c0.397,0.396,0.937,0.62,1.498,0.62 s1.101-0.224,1.498-0.62l5.473-5.476c0.826-0.827,0.826-2.167,0-2.994L55.931,47.463z"/>
 
  
</svg> 

</div>
```

Comment: Александр, это гениально и просто! А я бы сидел тут пыхтел еще не один час)
Вот теперь я познал svg думаю) с выводои use познакомился буквально на днях

Comment: @Nice у меня просто опыт, поэтому я два дня просил у вас код иконки :)))

Comment: Да, исчез я по работе. Вообще в другом деле увяз. Тут вспомнил утром - и бегом в стак)) Опыта видимо у вас уйма в этой области как и говорите)

Comment: Хотелось бы еще спросить -  приемлемо ли заменять <symbol> вместо <object> ?
И наоборот

Comment: @Nice `<object>` применяется когда файл лежит где-то на сетевом ресурсе и потом из файла по `id` вызывается определенная иконка. Если вы добавляете копированием svg непосредственно в HTML (инлайн способ), то можно обойтись без `<object>` Можно обойтись и без <symbol> в инлайновом варианте. Сейчас добавлю образец

Comment: Принял к сведению)

Comment: Единственное, что - через use не стилизуется под нужные размеры, видимо классы не переопределяются

Comment: @Nice Задайте новый вопрос про `use` и стилизацию. Только с вашим рабочим примером. И я подробно объясню, как это делается. Там много нюансов. В комментариях такие вопросы не решаются

Comment: @Nice Приветствую вас! Занят? Новогодний дедлайн? Я предложил создать вам, на основе вашего вопроса в комментариях, новый топик по вопросам использования `<use>`  Если вопрос актуален, задайте вопрос в новом топике, если совсем уже некогда, не забудьте сделать это после праздников :)) Вопрос и ответ будет полезен очень многим, так как он часто встречается

Comment: Александр, здравствуйте.
Да, действительно сейчас снова некогда, я после праздником смогу вернуться к этой теме) Кстати согласен - будет полезно очень многим данная тема. И с наступающим Новым 2019 Годом!!!

Comment: @Nice и тебя с наступающим Новым Годом! Желаю успехов в делах, чтобы получилось всё хорошее, что задумал. Удачи во всём и немножко удачи в освоении SVG

Comment: Моральная поддержка всегда действенна, думаю смогу добиться каких-никаких успехов в применении SVG. Спасибо! :)

Comment: @Nice вот посмотри кстати, что можно делать на SVG https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/905657/28748

Comment: Крутейшее использование!